# Geolocalizacion en un dataframe

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, estructuras-de-datos, geolocalización

tengo un data frame. con las columnas ciudades, latitud y longitud
las ciudades algunas tienen NaN otras estan completas. como puedo yo hacer para rellenar las columnas de ciudades con la longitud y latitud.
ejemplo

```
Mundo = {
        'ciudades': ['Nan', 'Buenos Aires', np.NaN,'Brasil','Canada'],
        'Lon': ['34.1577057', 'NaN', '22.1577057','','62.1577057'],
        'Lat': ['-95.2731303', 'NaN', '-102.2731303','','-80.2731303']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(Mundo)
```

la idea es que pueda rellenarse las filas vacias de la columna ciudades utilizando sus cordenadas gracias

Comment: Podrías usar [GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) por ejemplo teniendo cuidado con los limites de peticiones y condiciones de uso de cada api, pero tus datos son un poco incongruentes, en "ciudades" tienes a Brasil y Canadá, la latitud no puede ser inferior a -90º...

Comment: @FJSevilla     gracias por responder. no te preocupes por las coordendas si estan correctas o no, solo es un ejemplo. Yo Tambien estaba pensando en Geopy pero no sabia como aplicarlo para que me tome los datos de una columna y me rellene otra columna. Vos sabes como ?